# cannot read property $key of undefined in ionic 2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I am trying to update data in firebase in my ionic2 app and I get this error : 
`cannot read property '$key' of undefined`

.ts

```
onValidate(info): void{
  //console.log(info.$key);
  this.infos.update(info.$key,{
    FirstName : info.FirstName,
    LastName : info.LastName
  })
}
```

.html

```
<button
  ion-button
  type="submit"
  block
  [disabled]="!f.valid"
  (click)="onValidate(info)">Valider</button>
```

in my html I have an *ngFor = "let info of infos | async" ...

Thank you for your help

Comment: There is not enough code in your question to determine definitively. Presumably, `infos` is a `Promise` or `Observable` that is resolving with or pushing `undefined`

Comment: `infos` is `infos: FirebaseListObservable<any>`, do you need another information ? @Aluan Haddad

Comment: Yes, `undefined` is assignable to `any`. Using `any` in this context basically suppresses any possible type errors from bad map calls (missing returns or parens), accidentally mapping a void function over an observable, and tons of other mistakes. Do not use `any` except in incredibly rare cases comma of which this is not one since you clearly have an expected shape for the object. Anyway the simplest way to debug it is to subscribe to the observable in your viewmodel and simply log each value

Comment: thanks @AluanHaddad. I don't get how I log each value ?

Comment: In view model (.ts file) after you set `this.infos = whatever;` add `this.infos.subscribe(console.log)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using firebase here. You would never get the `$key` from angular `ngFor` as it is not apart of the structural array, because `$key` is an identifier, not a property in the firebase data structure.

What you can do it `push` the `$key` onto the array when you first get it. Although you do not show how you are getting `infos` i assume it would be something like.

```
this.api.get(`mydatabase/infos`).then(infosData => {
     this.infos = infodata;
});
```

In the returned promise you have access to `$key` which is where you can then push it into the array used in the view.

```
this.api.get(`mydatabase/infos`).then(infosData => {
   infosData.forEach((el,idx) => {
        console.log(el.$key);
        // Use the index as you should be pushing onto an object literal
        // Of course this could be different depending how you have 
        // structured the data being returned for firebase which is not
        // specified in your question
        infos[idx].push('key') = el.$key;
    }); 
});
```

Then your array being used in the view for the `ngFor` will now have a property `info.key` which you can use as an identifier in your `onValidate(info)` method.

Comment: Thank you !! @gerdi

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue, later I gone through the example code provided [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md). The key values are obtained from **snapshotChanges()**. So here, I used JSX spread attribute to store the key value for every child in the following way.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
      <input type="text" #updatetext [value]="item.text" />
      <button (click)="updateItem(item.key, updatetext.value)">Update</button>
      <button (click)="deleteItem(item.key)">Delete</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input type="text" #newitem />
  <button (click)="addItem(newitem.value)">Add</button>
  <button (click)="deleteEverything()">Delete All</button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  itemsRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.itemsRef = db.list('messages');
    // Use snapshotChanges().map() to store the key
    this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
  }
```